# Extending Twitter Bootstrap's Modal Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to extend the Twitter Bootstrap's Modal Plugin.
Is there a clean way to trigger an action when a modal popup is shown and hidden.

```
$("#xyz").clone().modal({"backdrop": "static", "keyboard":true, "show":true});
$("#xyz").on("shown", function(e){ console.log("hi");});
```

Tried the above but does nothing.

I don't want to specify the above function for all modal calls in my code.
What I really want is to make a generic function for all modal whenever shown or hidden.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're attaching the event handler to `$('#xyz')`, but you're creating a modal from `$('#xyz').clone()`, which is a separate object.

Try:

```
$("#xyz").on("shown", function(e){ console.log("hi");});
$("#xyz").clone(true).modal({"backdrop": "static", "keyboard":true, "show":true});
```

Attach the event handler first, and then clone it, making sure to pass `true` as an argument so that all event handlers and data attached to `$('#xyz')` are passed to the cloned object.

Comment: Awesome! Works great! Thanks a lot! Yeah, also realized, just need clone(true) instead of clone(true,true)